# Return index of smallest element in array

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I'm trying to return the index with the smallest element in an array of integers. Am I missing something? After I put my integers in, it doesn't return the index.

UPDATE: I get an error at the end of `int main()` about the array stack being corrupted. Thank you. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int indexofSmallestElement(double array[], int size);

int main()
{    
int size = 10; 
double array[10];

for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter an integer: " << endl;
    cin >> array[i];
}

indexofSmallestElement(array, size);
}

int indexofSmallestElement(double array[], int size)
{
int index = 0;

if (size != 1)
{

    int n = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < n)
        {
            n = array[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
}
return index;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be n = array[0], not the other way around? Since you want to save the first number as your assumed smallest element, then compare from there.

Comment: In addition to what @Clark said, also note that you discard the return value of indexofSmallestElement and don't display it. Also note that your loops use `<= size` which is *incorrect* - you should use `< size`. Remember, in C and C++ arrays start from 0, so if your array has 10 items, the valid indices are 0, 1, 2, ..., 9. Additionally, your `index` variable may be used uninitialized. Think of what happens when the smallest element is the first element.

Comment: Here is your stack corruption:  `for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)`.  Should be `<`

Comment: @PiotrSiupa the wording of close reason might be a bit confusing, but in principle I don't see any point opening it. First of all, the problem was a typical "off by 1", it was already edited, and is not reproducible anymore, so "close as typo" is a valid reason. Second, "idx of smallest elem" problem is widely known, I found 4 SO answers for C++ just by typing it in google.

Answer (score 17):

A number of people have shown you their variant of `indexofSmallestElement`. I will include mine along with an explanation of *why* I think it's better:

```
int indexofSmallestElement(double array[], int size)
{
    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] < array[index])
            index = i;              
    }

    return index;
}
```

You will notice that I do away with the `n` variable, which you used to hold the smallest value encountered so far. I did this because, in my experience, having to keep two different things synchronized can be a source of subtle bugs. Even in this simple case, it was the source of *multiple* bugs, not the least of which was that your `n` was declared an `int` but you were assigning values of type `double` in it.

**Bottom line**: do away with the `n` variable and just keep track of one thing: the index.

---

**Update**: of course, it goes without saying that with C++17 the *only* truly acceptable answer for this question is to use [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template <typename Iter>
auto indexofSmallestElement(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    return std::distance(first,
        std::min_element(first, last));
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
auto indexofSmallestElement(std::array<T, N> arr)
{
    return std::distance(std::begin(arr),
        std::min_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr)));
}

template <typename T>
auto indexofSmallestElement(std::vector<T> vec)
{
    return std::distance(std::begin(vec),
        std::min_element(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec)));
}


int main(int, char **)
{
    int arr[10] = { 7, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 9, 5, 6, 8 };

    auto x = indexofSmallestElement(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

    std::cout
        << "The smallest element in 'arr' is at index "
        << x << ": " << arr[x] << "\n";

    std::array<float, 5> fa { 0.0, 2.1, -1.7, 3.3, -4.2 };

    auto y = indexofSmallestElement(fa);

    std::cout
        << "The smallest element in 'fa' is at index "
        << y << ": " << fa[y] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for explanation. But the check for 1 is redundant - the loop condition will fail in the first instance if size=1.

Comment: You are, of course, correct. I think that was a left-over from a copy-paste of the code. Fixed.

Comment: I had a new error that I put in my original post. I tried your way, but it didn't fix it. Is it just me?

Comment: As I explained in a comment to your original post, your "new" error is caused by this loop in main: `for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)` Remember, in C and C++ arrays start from 0, so if your array has 10 items, the valid indices would be 0, 1, 2, ..., 9. Yet this loop will go from 0 to 10. In other words, you're trying to stuff 11 things in an array of 10 things. Your loop should be: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`

Answer (score 3):

It should be `n = array[0]` instead of `array[0] = n`. It means you are supposing first element of the array to be the smallest in the beginning and then comparing it with others.

Moreover in your loop, you are exceeding the bound of your array. The for loop should run till `i < size` and not `i <= size`.

Your code should be like this..

```
int indexofSmallestElement(double array[], int size)
{
  int index = 0 ;
  double n = array[0] ;
  for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
  {
    if (array[i] < n)
    {
        n = array[i] ;
        index = i ;
    }
  }
 return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the loop use array[i] and index = i. Size is the boundary :)